# Wont find item on each refresh. Loop is messed up

Tags: python, selenium

So I have this program and on each refresh I need it to look for an item until that item appears. Right now the loop I have does not work as I tested it I am not exactly sure how to code it.

```
driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories")
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article[.//a[contains(.,'Bike')]] 
[.//a[.='Red']]//a")
while True:
time.sleep(1.2)
if items:
   items[0].click()
   break
else:
   driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories")
```

Comment: Try to be more clear on what you mean by *your solution not working*. Are you not finding the elements you want even though they appear in you page?

Comment: @Lafa yeah when the new elements show up that im looking for it does not find it, but if the elements are on the page the first time it finds them. Its like after refreshing it doesnt look for the elements each time. Im pretty sure thats what I need it to do.

Comment: By accessing the page *right now* I could find only one unique element of those that interest you. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would do the trick for you:

```
links_visited = []

while True:

driver.get("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/accessories")

items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//article[.//a[contains(.,'Bike')]] 
[.//a[.='Red']]//a""")

links = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in items]


for link in links:
    if link in links_visited:
        print "link already visited! skipping..."
        continue

    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(5)
    links_visited.append(link)
    #do what you have to do here...

time.sleep(3)
```